# Changing elements to lowercase issues

Tags: javascript

I'm building a dynamic list of trees that starts with Oak, Pine, Aspen, Bald Cypress.

Which includes a button to add a 'Redwood' tree to the end of the list, and a 'Pear' tree to the start of the list.

I then included a button that onclick would change the strings to lowercase but I can't seem to get it right. I know the push() method will add the lowercase strings to the end of the list but I can't figure out how to get rid of the old strings with uppercase letters, and it also keeps adding more items to the list when the button is pushed again. I also tried the map method, however it did not seem to work unless created a new variable.

```
    const trees = ['Oak', 'Pine', 'Aspen', 'Bald Cypress']

    const listTrees = () => {
        let treeList = ''
        trees.forEach(tree => {
            //console.log(tree)
            treeList += `${tree} <br>`
        })
        displayResults.innerHTML = `${treeList} <span>${trees.length} elements 
        long</span>`
    }

    listTrees()

    * ------adding redwood to the end ------------*/
    document.querySelector('#add_redwood').onclick = () => {
        trees.push('Redwood')
        listTrees()
    }

    /* --------------------adding a pear to the start ----------------------*/
    document.querySelector('#add_pear').onclick = () => {
        trees.unshift('Pear')
        listTrees()
    }

    document.querySelector('#lowerTrees').onclick = () => {
        trees.forEach(tree => {
            trees.push(tree.toLowerCase())
        })
     listTrees()
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare trees with `let` instead of `const` then reassign it. There is no reason for you to keep the original array reference in this case. Then you can use `map()`. You can also use `map()` for `listTrees()`.

```js
const displayResults = document.querySelector("#displayResults");

let trees = ['Oak', 'Pine', 'Aspen', 'Bald Cypress']

const listTrees = () => {
    let treeList = trees.map(tree => `${tree}<br>`).join("");
    displayResults.innerHTML = `${treeList} <span>${trees.length} elements long</span>`
}

listTrees()

/* ------adding redwood to the end------------ */
document.querySelector('#add_redwood').onclick = () => {
    trees.push('Redwood')
    listTrees()
}

/* --------------------adding a pear to the start ----------------------*/
document.querySelector('#add_pear').onclick = () => {
    trees.unshift('Pear')
    listTrees()
}

document.querySelector('#lowerTrees').onclick = () => {
    trees = trees.map(tree => tree.toLowerCase());
    listTrees();
}
```

```html
<button id="add_redwood">Add Redwood</button>
<button id="add_pear">Add Pear</button>
<button id="lowerTrees">Lower Trees</button>
<div id="displayResults"></div>
```

If you really want to keep `tree` as `const`, use a regular for loop to change each element one by one instead.

```
for(let i = 0; i < trees.length; i++)
{
    trees[i] = trees[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I will just change the const to let, and works just fine! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to reassign lowercased values to HTML

```
 document.querySelector('#lowerTrees').onclick = () => {
    trees.forEach(tree => {
        trees.push(tree.toLowerCase())
    })
 listTrees()
 }
```

Comment: don't forget to clear the dom first 
displayResults.innerHTML = ''